# Loops and totals in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to write a program to draw a histogram of the lengths of words present in a list, so far I am up the stage of increasing the number of words present of a certain length by one every time the loop finds a word with that certain length, at the moment I have:

```
L = []
for i in range(L):
length = len(i)
for len(i) = 1:
    total1 = total1 + 1
for len(i) = 2:
    total2= total2 + 1
for len(i) = 3:
    total3 = total3 + 1
for len(i) = 4:
    total4 = total4 + 1
for len(i) = 5:
    total5 = total5 + 1
```

However clearly this is a stupid method as it involved naming each version of totaln, where in this case n would be up to 11, so my question is can I simply put

```
L = []
for i in range(L):
length = len(i)
for len(i) = n:
    totaln = totaln + 1
```

to cover all values of n, and then refer to for example total4 later? Or will the interpreter return an error as total4 isn't explicitly defined?

As for the rest of the code I think I can work that bit out, it's just this issue I am having trouble with, being very new to programming.

Comment: Neither of those snippets are valid Python code.

Comment: I pasted only that section as it was only the part that is relevant, it is nowhere near done as I just quickly typed that out, also I have only been doing this for 4 weeks and don't have much of an idea what I'm doing.

Comment: @George: It is hard to tell for the reader what things like `for len(i) = n:` are supposed to mean, because these strange lines have almost nothing in common with Python snytax.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, sorry I have a bad habit of doing that, I keep trying to summarise values with arbitrary letters so it is easier to refer to them later, however this is at the cost of it being difficult to follow. I am just trying to take a list of words (about 55,000 words) and create a tally for the amount of times a words of a certain length appear e.g. there are 13,000 words with a length of 5 letters. Sorry if I'm making it confusing.

Comment: @George: You are missing the point.  `for len(i) = n:` isn't Python, regardless how the names in it are defined, and it's very hard to figure out what you think this lines should be doing.  Basically you are making up your own language and expect people to understand the language you just invented.

Comment: @Sven It says a lot about how ignorant I am in terms of Python. I just (wrongly) assumed if you can iterate over a list L by using L[i] then you could refer to each item in the list L by simply writing i. I know that the code I put down is crappy, but I am trying to use stuff that I have already been taught, because otherwise I'll just end up pasting lots of code in that I don't understand. The problem is at the moment I am so new to this, I can't tell that what I wrote down is a load of rubbish, I'm sorry for wasting your time, I'll stop posting all these stupid comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.7 or above, you could use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
a = ["basically", "in", "Python", "I", "am", "trying", "to", "write",
     "a", "program", "to", "draw", "a", "histogram", "of", "the",
     "lengths", "of", "words", "present", "in", "a", "list"]
print Counter(map(len, a))
```

prints

```
Counter({2: 7, 1: 4, 7: 3, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 9: 2, 3: 1})
```

which is a dictionary mapping word lengths to frequencies.

Comment: Will this count occurences of the same word?

Comment: @George: How about trying to find out yourself?  After all it's your work, and unless you are trying to understand the answers, they will be utterly useless to your progress in programming.

Comment: I am sorry Sven but I am new at this, I have never come across 'counter' or half of the terms used here, I have been learning this for 4 weeks so I'm sorry if I don't understand what this means, but I am trying to learn by asking experts and then taking some of the tips and seeing how I can apply it to what I have to do.

Comment: @George: I didn't want to sound rude, and there's no need to apologize.  My point was that you didn't ask "how is this working?", or "what is `Counter`?" or anything that would have helped your understanding.  I'll add a link to the documentation.

Comment: I tried googling Counter to find out what it meant to see if this was applicable but I don't understand the definition.
Also the code you posted looks like it will do the job :) One question however I don't really understand the last line, is map an inbuilt function that will search through the list a to return length: number of occurences?

Comment: @George: Yes, [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) is a built-in function.  I'd recommend you to read the official Python tutorial.  It is well-written and contains a [section on `map()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools).

Comment: ah man, there I go writing a detailed answer/example and an accepted answer comes a long =) Good Job. =)

Comment: @matchew I appreciate your effort regardless, I am probably 10 years away from understanding what any of it means but it looks like it does exactly what I needed. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @SvenMarnach You are right, I may deactivate this account so I can try and learn as much as I can without being tempted to ask for help. However I have 6 days in which to learn enough to write this program so the outlook is bleak.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question but will be more helpful in the long run.

Your Python knowledge is nearly non-existent.  I've reviewed your other questions and it looks like you are trying run before you've learned to walk.  Pick a tutorial from [Python for Non-Programmers](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) and *work through* all examples.  Ask questions here when a specific concept doesn't make sense.

After clicking through the tutorials I think [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist - 2nd edition](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/) would be most appropriate.  It includes excellent exercises at the end of each chapter.

Comment: Exactly! It's like trying to write an essay in Latin for me at the moment, and as much as I want to learn Python right from the beginning so I understand it properly, I have to hand in a piece of work in the next week on it, so I simply don't have the time, which is why I am trying to bodge together code in the hope it will work, I will work trhough as many of those tutorials as I can, thanks for the link and honest advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have a base structure with something like this:

```
words = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words', 'that', 'I', 'want', 'to', 'measure']
```

You can use this to count the lengths:

```
from collections import defaultdict

totals = defaultdict(int)

for word in words:
  totals[len(word)] += 1
```

Comment: Would this count the occurences of strings with a certain number of letters?

Comment: @GeorgeBurrows - This counts based on the length of the word, yes.  That's where `len(word)` comes in.

Comment: Does python interpret a singular as being part of the list of plurals in every case? I.e. an example I looked at had a list of food called meals and then it had "for meal in meals", would this be the case for every example i.e. "for cat in cats" where cats is a list?

Comment: @GeorgeBurrows - No.  The syntax for the `for` loop is `for <item> in <iterable>:`.  Iterable is a collection of some sort (list, dictionary, etc.) and Item is a placeholder for each value of the iterable.  As far as learning goes, I'd suggest http://learnpythonthehardway.org/.  It starts with the very basic and progresses to the moderately advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for the Natural Language Tool Kit ([NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book))
The toolkit may be a bit too powerfull for what you are trying to do,
but it might also be a shortcut. No sense in reinventing the wheel
to generate a plot.

for example, assume I have the following text (temp.txt)

> How much wood would a woodchuck chuck
> If a woodchuck could chuck wood?
> He would chuck, he would, as much as he could,
> And chuck as much wood as a woodchuck would
> If a woodchuck could chuck wood.

here is the code to generate and plot a simple freqDist

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize as tokenize
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.text import Text
def freqDist(infile):
  '''tokenize and return a simple fd'''
  fn = open('/home/matt/temp','r') 
  tokens = tokenize(fn.read())
  fn.close()
  t = Text(tokens)
  fd = FreqDist(t)
  return fd
```

--

Assuming you do not use the function lets look at what the following gives us

```
>>> tokens
['How', 'much', 'wood', 'would', 'a', 'woodchuck', 'chuck', 'If', 'a', 'woodchuck', 'could', 'chuck', 'wood', '?', 'He', 'would', 'chuck', ',', 'he', 'would', ',', 'as', 'much', 'as', 'he', 'could', ',', 'And', 'chuck', 'as', 'much', 'wood', 'as', 'a', 'woodchuck', 'would', 'If', 'a', 'woodchuck', 'could', 'chuck', 'wood', '.']
>>> t
<Text: How much wood would a woodchuck chuck If...>
>>> fd
<FreqDist with 43 outcomes>
>>> fd[wood]
4
```

and finally

```
>>#Freq of the top five words
>>fd.plot(10)
```

[image: Freq of the top five words]

## But, You Want token lengths!

which we can generate with a simple modification of the code

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize as tokenize
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.text import Text

def fDist(infile):
    '''tokenize and return a simple fd'''
    fn = open(infile,'r') 
    tokens = tokenize(fn.read())
    token_lengths = [len(token) for token in tokens]
    #if you do not want to include only words (not punctuation)
    #token_lengths = [len(token) for token in tokens if token.isalpha()]
    fn.close()
    t = Text(token_lengths)
    fd = FreqDist(t)
    return fd
```

so...

```
>>fd=Fdist('/home/user/temp.txt')
>>fd.plot()
```

[image: Freq Dist of Word Len]

Lets put it together to make something usefull and reuseable

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize as tokenize
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.text import Text
import sys

def fDist(infile):
    '''tokenize and return a simple fd'''
    fn = open(infile,'r') 
    tokens = tokenize(fn.read())
    token_lengths = [len(token) for token in tokens]
    #if you do not want to include only words (not punctuation)
    #token_lengths = [len(token) for token in tokens if token.isalpha()]
    fn.close()
    t = Text(token_lengths)
    fd = FreqDist(t)
    return fd

def main():
   fd = fDist(sys.argv[1])
   fd.plot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

now you can call the above from the cmd line as follows:

```
  ./fdist.py infile.txt
```

you could probably go ahead and add some checks to make sure you have a valid file, but thats beyond the scope of this question.